# Exact Positioning When using Drag and Drop in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, drag-and-drop, swt, windowbuilder

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop functionality for a GUI I'm creating using WindowBuilder/ SWT Designer. At present, in order to determine where exactly on the canvas the drop takes place, I use

```
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        int x = event.x - shell.getBounds().x - canvas.getBounds().x;
        int y = event.y - shell.getBounds().y - canvas.getBounds().y;
        e.gc.drawString(d, x, y);
    }
});
```

But this is not an exact positioning at the mouse drop, instead it is very much further towards the right. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please post a complete testable code snippet.

Comment: @Baz I've added the complete part implementing the drag and drop. I can't see how it'll be testable until I include my entire code...

Comment: Well, what I meant is: Please post a complete but minimal code snippet that shows your problem. It's hard to tell what's going on without being able to test it in my own IDE.

Comment: @Baz Ok I've added the needful.

Comment: You're code doesn't compile and throws an exception once I fixed one of the issues...

Comment: @Baz Sorry! I checked again this time. I promise the code compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the very helpful function `Control#toControl(int, int)`:

> Returns a point which is the result of converting the argument, which is specified in display relative coordinates, to coordinates relative to the receiver.

```
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener()
{
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
    {
        Point point = canvas.toControl(event.x, event.y);
        e.gc.drawString(d, point.x, point.y);
    }
});
```

That'll do it.